# Newline axis labels exporting to SVG

Tags: svg, highcharts

In [this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/qnuwcgns/), I have to split the x axis labels in two lines

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        useHTML: true
    },
    categories: ['unter 1.000 €', '1.000 bis <br /> 1.499 €', '1.500 bis <br /> 1.999 €', '2.000 bis <br /> 2.499 €', '2.500 bis <br /> 2.999 €', '3.000 bis <br /> 3.999 €', '4.000 bis <br /> 4.999 €', '5.000 €  <br /> und mehr']
},
```

It works well in the browser, but when I export it to SVG (or another format), it displays in this way:
[image: chart as SVG]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the ["Labels and string formatting"](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting#html) documentation:

> Most places where text is handled in Highcharts, it is also followed by an option called `useHTML`...
>
> The downsides are that it will always be laid out on top of all other SVG content, and that it is not rendered the same way in exported charts.

A workaround is to use the "allow html" patch for export, and set `export.allowHTML: true`. This is mentioned in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2473).

You can add the patch using this code:

```
/**
 * This snippet adds support for useHTML in exported charts, opening for advanced
 * HTML features like positioning, tables, layout etc. Images will probably not
 * work well because the server doesn't know how to preload them.
 * Note that the rendering agent needs to support the SVG foreignObject tag. The 
 * featured Highcharts export server is based on PhantomJS which supports this. Other 
 * SVG renderers, like Batik or Inkscape, do not support it.
 */
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'init', function (proceed, options, callback) {
        if (options.chart && options.chart.forExport) {
            options.chart.forExport = options.exporting.allowHTML !== true;
        }
        proceed.call(this, options, callback);        
    });
    H.wrap(H.Chart.prototype, 'sanitizeSVG', function (proceed, svg) {
        
        // Move HTML into a foreignObject
        var html = svg.match(/<\/svg>(.*?$)/);
        if (html) {
            html = '<foreignObject x="0" y="0 width="200" height="200">' +
                '<body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">' +
                html[1] +
                '</body>' + 
                '</foreignObject>';

            svg = svg.replace('</svg>', html + '</svg>');
        } 
        return proceed.call(this, svg);
        
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

Then add this piece of code to your chart options:

```
exporting: {
    allowHTML: true
}
```

And see [this updated JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/qnuwcgns/1/) of how it works with your chart.